# Set divider position of SplitPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to set the divider of a SplitPane to a certain default position. This does not work, the divider stays in the middle:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(new Pane(), new Pane());

    // Report changes to the divider position
    splitPane.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty().addListener(
            o -> System.out.println(splitPane.getDividerPositions()[0])
    );

    // Doesn't work:
    splitPane.setDividerPositions(0.8);

    // The docs seem to recommend the following (with floats instead of
    // doubles, and with one number more than there are dividers, which is
    // weird), but it doesn't work either:
    //splitPane.setDividerPositions(0.8f, 0.2f);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(splitPane));
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

The output:

```
0.8
0.5
```

[image: screenshot of result]

It suggests that something resets it to the middle.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14):

The issue seems to be that the divider position is reset when the `SplitPane` width is set during when the `Stage` is maximized. Set the divider positions afterwards by listening to the window's showing property as follows:

```java
primaryStage.showingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            splitPane.setDividerPositions(0.8);
            observable.removeListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

During `Stage` initialization, window size changes several times until layout is completed. Every change modifies divider positions. If you want to control divider positions, they have to be set *after* `Stage` is fully initialized:

```
private boolean m_stageShowing = false;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(new Pane(), new Pane());

    ChangeListener<Number> changeListener = new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            splitPane.setDividerPositions(0.8);
            if (m_stageShowing) {
                observable.removeListener(this);
            }
        }
    };
    splitPane.widthProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    splitPane.heightProperty().addListener(changeListener);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(splitPane));
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.show();
    m_stageShowing = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the above solutions where not working reliably for me.
So I created a custom skin for SplitPane:

```
public class DumbSplitPaneSkin extends SplitPaneSkin {

  public DumbSplitPaneSkin(SplitPane splitPane) {
    super(splitPane);
  }

  @Override
  protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
    double[] dividerPositions = getSkinnable().getDividerPositions();
    super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, h);
    getSkinnable().setDividerPositions(dividerPositions);
  }
}
```

This skin can be used via css or by overriding SplitPane.createDefaultSkin(). You can also set programatically as splitPane.setSkin(new DumbSplitPaneSkin(splitPane));

Comment: This is exactly what i would expect the SplitPane to act like in the first place... sometimes "clever" is not always good.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others the issue is that the divider position is reset when the Stage is maximized.

You can prevent this by setting `ResizableWithParent` to `false`.

**Example**

Let's say you have a `SplitPane` with two nested containers inside. Here is the fxml extract:

```
<SplitPane fx:id="splitPane" dividerPositions="0.25">
        <VBox fx:id="leftSplitPaneContainer" />
        <FlowPane fx:id="rightSplitPaneContainer"/>
</SplitPane>
```

And here is the extract from the controller class:

```
@FXML
private SplitPane splitPane;
@FXML
private VBox leftSplitPaneContainer;
@FXML
private FlowPane rightSplitPaneContainer;
```

Then you simply can call `SplitPane.setResizableWithParent()` on both containers to prevent resetting the divider position:

```
public void initialize(){
        SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(leftSplitPaneContainer, false);
        SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(rightSplitPaneContainer, false);
    }
```

The divider position will now remain at 0.25 even if you maximize the window.

No complicated listeners or overwriting of `SplitPaneSkin` involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the call `setDividerPositions` with

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                splitPane.setDividerPositions(0.8);

            }
        });
```

This is not 100% reliable solution because `run()` method is performed in JFX thread at unspecified time but it works properly for simple initialization cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my result:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.*;

/**
 * SplitPane, Dialogbox example
 * @author Pataki István
 */
public class SimpleDocking extends Application {

  private double splitPosition = 0;
  private SplitPane rootPane = new SplitPane();
  private MyDialog dialog;
  private BorderPane dockedArea;

  @Override
  public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    rootPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    rootPane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(
                                    Color.GREEN,
                                    BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
                                    new CornerRadii(5),
                                    new BorderWidths(3))
    ));

    dockedArea = new BorderPane(new TextArea("Some docked content"));
    final FlowPane centerArea = new FlowPane();
    final Button undockButton = new Button("Undock");
    centerArea.getChildren().add(undockButton);
    rootPane.getItems().addAll(centerArea, dockedArea);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(rootPane, 300, 300));
    stage.show();

    dialog = new MyDialog(stage);
    undockButton.disableProperty().bind(dialog.showingProperty());
    undockButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        handler(stage);
      }
    });
  }

  private void handler(Stage stage) {
    splitPosition = rootPane.getDividerPositions()[0];
    rootPane.getItems().remove(dockedArea);
    dialog.setOnHidden(windowEvent -> {
      rootPane.getItems().add(dockedArea);
      rootPane.setDividerPositions(splitPosition);
    });
    dialog.setContent(dockedArea);
    dialog.show(stage);
  }

  private class MyDialog extends Popup {
    private BorderPane root;

    private MyDialog(Window parent) {
      root = new BorderPane();
      root.setPrefSize(200, 200);
      root.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-color: gray");
      root.setTop(buildTitleBar());
      setX(parent.getX() + 50);
      setY(parent.getY() + 50);
      getContent().add(root);
    }

    public void setContent(Node content) {
      root.setCenter(content);
    }

    private Node buildTitleBar() {
      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
      pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: burlywood; -fx-padding: 5");
      final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();

      pane.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
        dragDelta.x = getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
        dragDelta.y = getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
      });

      pane.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
        setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
        setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
      });

      Label title = new Label("My Dialog");
      title.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: midnightblue;");
      pane.setLeft(title);

      Button closeButton = new Button("X");
      closeButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> hide());
      pane.setRight(closeButton);
      return pane;
    }
  }

  private static class Delta {
    double x, y;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    launch();
  }
}
```

This is works like you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Since you usually have at least something in splitpane, eg. vbox, just set min and max width and it will automatically set divider.

Answer (score 0):

`Platform.runlater(()->splitpane.setDividerPosition(0,0.8));`

Absolutely does the trick for me. This sets the first split position of my horizontal splitpane to 80% of the parents width when opening the window.

While runlater() in many cases can lead JavaFX to do a little visible jitter at times, depending on the complexity of your GUI, in my case I haven't seen this happen.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
splitPane.setDividerPosition(0, percentage);
```

The parameters are setDividerPosition(int dividerIndex, double percentage)

Comment: That's essentially the same thing as what I posted and yields exactly the same result. And it's a value between 0.0 and 1.0, not really a percentage.

Comment: Yeah. It might be an order of operations thing. Try adding a button and putting the method in there.

Comment: Great, that works! But it has to be there before user interaction. Sigh. Any idea besides setting an ugly timer?

Comment: Doing the setDividerPosition _after_ `primaryStage.show()` seems to work. Sometimes.