# How to set a SplitPane divider location at startup from Preferences

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

Below a workaround to set a SplitPane divider location at startup. I'm looking for a better solution.

Controller class fragment:

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
   final Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage( getClass());
   final double position = prefs.getDouble( "divider", -1.0 );
   if( position > 0 ) {
      Platform.runLater(()
         -> Platform.runLater(()
            -> _splipane.setDividerPosition( 0, position )));
   }
}
```

FXML fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<SplitPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
   fx:controller="..."
   fx:id="_splipane"
   orientation="HORIZONTAL"
   dividerPositions="0.25">
   <items>
      ...
```

EDIT : I've found [another answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290539/set-divider-position-of-splitpane) but no solution

Comment: This *might* be totally unrelated, but I know that in Swing, setting the divider location *at startup* also required a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` (analogous to your `Platform.runLater`). Although I think that **one** `Platform.runLater` should be enough. For my part, I simply anticipated that (wrote a utility method for that, and just called it). Is there any particular problem with your workaround (besides looking a bit suspicious and confusing for someone who doesn't know what the issue is here)?

Comment: This workaround works pretty well. I have to postpone treatment twice, once isn't enough.

Comment: Well, IMHO, pulling it into a utility method like `Utils.setDividerLocation(splitPane, 0.1)` with a JavaDoc comment like `/* Must be, otherwise teh codez not workz */` should be fine, but I agree that *knowing* what causes the divider location to be "overridden" during initialization would be nice. The high-level reason is: At some point, the layout manager runs and messes things up. I doubt that there is a more resonable way to *prevent* this, but would also be curious to see one.

Comment: Try forcing a layout on the splitpane before setting the divider position: it might be that the splitpane can't properly compute the min/max sizes of the items in the splitpane before layout is performed: `splipane.layout(); splipane.setDividerPosition(..);`

Comment: I have tested just yet and no, it's not working properly. Workaround still in place... ;-)