# JavaFX split pane divider position not working

Tags: javafx, splitpane

I have a split pane with a initial divider position set to 0.2, the problem is that after running the application the position is changed to 0.5, I read that it is due to `stage.setMaximized(true);`
I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290539/set-divider-position-of-splitpane), but the answers imply that the current split pane and the main stage are in the same class, but in my case, I have to work in a controller class.

I tried to add a listener to the stage showing property `Main.getStage().showingProperty().addListener(...)` in the `initialize()` method, but it doesn't work, it says stage is null, I guess it's because initialize() runs before `Main.start()`

So how can I make my split pane start with a fixed divider position?

Thanks!

## **EDIT :**

I made a simple example to expose my problem :

**Main**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
  FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("views/test.fxml"));
  mainStage=primaryStage;
  mainStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
  mainStage.show();
  Controller_Test ct=loader.getController();
  System.out.println("Main:"+ct.sp.getDividerPositions()[0]);
  ct.getDividerPos();
}
```

**Controller_Test**

```
@FXML
public SplitPane sp;

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    System.out.println("Initialize:"+sp.getDividerPositions()[0]);
}

public void getDividerPos(){
    System.out.println("Method:"+sp.getDividerPositions()[0]);
}
```

Now I set the split pane divider at 1, which means the second pane should not show, I run the application and here is the result :

[image: window at launch]

Okay for this one, the divider is at 1, so only one pane is showing, now I will maximize the window :

[image]

The divider position clearly changed.
If you read the code I provide previously, you can see 3 print lines as checkpoints, here is their output after running the application :

> Initialize:1.0
> Main:0.9933110367892977
> Method:0.9933110367892977

Thanks!

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: See [`SplitPane#setResizableWithParent(Node,Boolean)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html#setResizableWithParent(javafx.scene.Node,java.lang.Boolean)).

Comment: @kleopatra, I edited the post and added an example.

Comment: @Slaw, my question isn't related to split pane size.

Comment: When you resize the window the `SplitPane` changes size. This causes the `SplitPane` to resize its children by default, leading to the divider(s) changing position, but that behavior can be disabled with the method I linked to.

Comment: @Slaw, thanks for your answer, I tried your method but the result is slightly the same, the red pane is thinner than before but still showing, I guess the divider at 1 should not let the second pane to appear.
Here is what I tried :  
```SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(sp,false);```  
```for(Node node : sp.getItems()){
    SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(node,false);
}```

`System.out.println(SplitPane.isResizableWithParent(sp));`  
After running, the divider position is : 0.9933110367892977.

Comment: Problem seems to be related to making every child not resizable-with-parent. If you only make the rightmost node not resizable-with-parent then the behavior would seem to fit your needs.

Comment: @Slaw, problem solved, except that I had to make the LEFT node not resizable, (making the right one seems to only work with the divider at 1).
Thanks for your help and efforts!